# Error handling with curl and elasticsearch

Tags: bash, http, curl, elasticsearch, error-handling

I'm currently developing bash scripts that use elasticsearch and I need a good error-handling.
In this situation I try to add a document to elasticsearch and check if the operation succeeded.

At first I naively tried this :

```
response=$(curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/indexation/document' -d '
{
  "content":"'"$txt"'",,
  "date_treatment":"'"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"'"
}') && echo ok || echo fail
```

But curl doesn't work that way and still returns success (0 - which is actually logical) even though the json request is obviously incorrect (note the double comma on line 3) and elasticsearch displays errors.

So the answer isn't there. Now I think I should analyze the variable $response to catch errors (grep ?). I post this question to get hints or solutions on the way to do this in a reliable way and to make sure I'm not missing an obvious solution (maybe a curl option I don't know ?).

**Additional useful things**

[Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Examples of the content of $response :

success :

```
{
    "_id": "AVQz7Fg0nF90YvJIX_2C",
    "_index": "indexation",
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 1,
        "total": 1
    },
    "_type": "document",
    "_version": 1,
    "created": true
}
```

error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "caused_by": {
            "reason": "json_parse_exception: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@139163f; line: 3, column: 17]",
            "type": "json_parse_exception"
        },
        "reason": "failed to parse",
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "reason": "json_parse_exception: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@139163f; line: 3, column: 17]",
                "type": "json_parse_exception"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: Try printing the status of `response` by adding  `echo $?` after the line in the script you have.

Comment: Both what I call "success" and "failure" returns $?. That's basically what I tried with `&& echo ok || echo fail` but when I give elasticsearch a bad request it's not curl failing, it's elasticsearch.

Comment: (can't edit for some reasons) I meant return $?=0 (success)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple workaround is to use the `-f/--fail` option.

As per [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) :

> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is
>   mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed
>   attempts. In normal cases when an HTTP server fails to deliver a
>   document, it returns an HTML document stating so (which often also
>   describes why and more). This flag will prevent curl from outputting
>   that and return error 22.
>
> This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where
>   non-successful response codes will slip through, especially when
>   authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

example:

```
response=$(curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/indexation/document' -d '
{
  "content":"'"$txt"'",,
  "date_treatment":"'"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"'"
}' -f ) && echo ok || echo fail
```

Comment: Thank you, this option is exactly what I was looking for !